# Can I close a merge request on drupal.org I opened by mistake if I am not the module maintainer?

Tags: community-official-site

While setting up a merge request for drupal.org, I pushed my code, which opened one merge request, and clicked the "Open merge request" button, which opened a second (empty) merge request.

Is it possible for me to close this empty merge request that I opened by mistake if I am not the module maintainer?

Comment: I assume, you can ask it for module maintainers, they can cancel empty merge requests.

Comment: You should be able to market it 'closed, won't fix', then attach a message marking it as a duplicate/accident.

Comment: @Jaypan Are you talking about the issue or the merge request?  The problem is with an issue that has two merge requests, one empty and one that actually fixes the issue.